# MYSQL Stored Proc: How to delete a just updated record

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have two table Name: registeredList & deregisteredlist. Now when a user getting getting deregistered from "registeredlist" table then a trigger update his info to deregistration table and delete the record from registration table. On my below proc i can update it properly but can't delete the user from registered table. My proc:

```
DELIMITER $$
USE `abc_db`$$
DROP TRIGGER  `UnsubscriberListTrigger`$$
CREATE        
    TRIGGER `UnsubscriberListTrigger` AFTER UPDATE ON `registeredlist` FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN        
     IF (old.SubscriberStatus='registered') THEN    
       INSERT INTO deregisteredlist(name,SubscriberStatus,DeRegistrationDate) 
       VALUES(old.name,'Deregistered',NOW());

       DELETE from registeredlist where old.id=new.id;/???????/I am getting problem here           
     END IF;
 END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think all you need is to change `WHERE` in `DELETE` statement.
It should go like this:

```
DELETE from registeredlist where id=old.id; // (or new.id cause in this case old.id is equal to new.id)
```

... because you want to match it against `id` column.

**UPDATE:**

Another possibility is this:
- create AFTER INSERT TRIGGER on `deregisteredlist` which will do the DELETE in `registeredlist`. That way you shouldn't get that error.

Comment: Thanks. I used it But getting the error when update the registeredlist table: ERROR: Can't update table 'registeredlist' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
DELETE from registeredlist order by updateddat desc limit 1;
```